# How can I get awstats to read this log format?

Tags: logging, apache2, awstats, log-analysis

I have a site with several subdomains, all subdomains are logged to the same access_log file. Since the file can be so huge, I have a script that greps out each subdomain into its own file.

I have a custom log file format in Apache like so:

```
"\"%{Host}i\" %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\""
```

A line from my log file looks like this:

```
"brand.mysite.com" 176.32.1.18 - - [24/Oct/2010:11:24:45 -0400] "GET /Product/lookup HTTP/1.1" 200 5585 "http://www.customerhomepage.com/brand_name.htm" "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; InfoPath.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)"
```

10 items in the log format, 10 items in the log. Check.

I'm trying to analyze these with awstats with the following Logformat in my awstats config file:

LogFormat="\"%host_r\" %host %logname %logname %time1 %methodurl %code %bytesd %refererquot %uaquot"

The only output I get from awstats is from the Monthly History section. Everything else is either blank or zero.

My generation script looks like this:

```
rm stats/*.txt
cat access_log | grep brand > brand_access_log
perl tools/awstats_updateall.pl -configdir=wwwroot/cgi-bin -awstatsprog=wwwroot/cgi-bin/awstats.pl now
perl tools/awstats_buildstaticpages.pl -dir=stats -output=pagetype -config=brand -awstatsprog=wwwroot/cgi-bin/awstats.pl
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't realize I could just cut and paste the Apache LogFormat directive (with an = sign) and it would work, I thought I was forced to use awstats.

awstats will use the LogFormat directive from your httpd.conf file and replace it with the awstats identifiers.

I cut and pasted this into my awstats.whatever.conf file directly from my Apache2 httpd.conf (and then added the = sign after LogFormat):

```
LogFormat="\"%{Host}i\" %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\""
```